# Android setAlarmClock triggering immediately

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I created a simple application to try out `setAlarmClock()`. There is only a single button in the `MainActivity`, and it calls `setAlarm` when clicked.

The code is below.

`MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "alarmclock.MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void setAlarm(View view) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        long nextTrigger = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+10*1000;
        Log.i(TAG, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + ": scheduling next alarm at " + nextTrigger);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo ac = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(nextTrigger, null);
        alarmManager.setAlarmClock(ac, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

`AlarmReceiver`

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "alarmclock.AlarmReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + " in AlarmReceiver onReceive()");
    }
}
```

I am basically triggering the alarm for 10seconds later, but for some reason it's triggering immediately.

```
2020-09-21 22:09:56.664 17910-17910/com.example.alarmclock I/alarmclock.MainActivity: 3362358: scheduling next alarm at 3372358
2020-09-21 22:09:56.687 17910-17910/com.example.alarmclock I/alarmclock.AlarmReceiver: 3362382 in AlarmReceiver onReceive()
```

If I use `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` the same code seems to work fine. But I am specifically wanting to try out `setAlarmClock`.

Comment: what is the "null" after the "nextTrigger" in the "ac = ..." code line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [AlarmClockInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo#AlarmClockInfo(long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) requires a wall time:

> time at which the underlying alarm is triggered in wall time milliseconds since the epoch

but you are using `elapsedRealtime()` time so use `System.currentTimeMillis` to fix the issue.

Comment: found out shortly after and posted an answer about the same time. but thanks for replying so quickly!

Comment: @chongzixin Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

It worked after I changed from `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` to `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

```
long nextTrigger = System.currentTimeMillis()+10*1000
```

After reading the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo) in greater detail, I realise that the first parameter of the `AlarmClockInfo` constructor takes

> long: time at which the underlying alarm is triggered in wall time
> milliseconds since the epoch

which is what `System.currentTimeMillis()` gives.

On the other hand, `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` returns the

> time since the system was booted...

which will always be a much smaller number than wall time since epoch. As a result, the alarm gets scheduled immediately because

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately.